# JOptionPane message showing null

Tags: java, swing

we are working on a project trying to make a message in a JOptionPane show up when a button is pressed and certain conditions are met. However whenever the code is activated and a button is pressed, the JOptionPane shows up with no message. Here is the code that creates the GUI

```
 package BlackJack;
 import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
 import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
 import javax.swing.*;

public class BlckJckUI {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame GUI = new JFrame("Blackjack Advisor");
    GUI.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GUI.setSize(1000,900);
    GUI.setVisible(true);
 JButton two = new JButton(Two);
    two.setSize(300, 100);
    two.setLocation(100, 200);
    two.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
            Arrays array = new Arrays();
            Math math = new Math();
            math.cardvalue = 2;
            array.clicktracker++;

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array.result);
        }
    });
   GUI.add(two);
```

This is the code that works out the logic.

```
package BlackJack;

public class Math {
public int cardvalue;
public Math()
{

    Arrays array = new Arrays();

    if (array.clicktracker == 1)
    {   
        array.dealer = cardvalue;   
        array.result = "Please select the first card you have :)";


    }
    else if (array.clicktracker == 2)
    {

        array.playerhand.add(cardvalue);
        array.result = "Please select the second card you have :)";

    }
    else if (array.clicktracker >= 3)
    {
        array.playerhand.add(cardvalue);
        if (array.playerhandtotal <= 8)
        {

            // array.result = result statement
            array.result = "You should just hit until you're safe. If the dealer 6 or below,\n"
                + " the chances are that he'll bust and if not, remain low above 17.\n"
                + " As long as you can pull a 17 or higher, you should be safe. Pick \n"
                + "another card or reset.";
```

This is the code that creates the Array and variables associated with it.

```
package BlackJack;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arrays{
  public String result = null;
    ArrayList<Integer> playerhand = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    public int dealer = 0;
    public int clicktracker = 0;
    public int playerhandtotal = 0;
    {
    for (int element: playerhand)
     {
         playerhandtotal = element + playerhandtotal;
     }
    System.out.println(result);
    System.out.println(dealer);
    System.out.println(clicktracker);
     }
}
```

Comment: I assume this is because you define `Arrays` and `Math` within the `actionPerformed` method, but `Math` has it's own `Arrays` reference, which you are ignoring...

Comment: I remember this post from yesterday, way clearer code and a way better job of showing relevant parts. +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating two separate instances of your `Arrays` class. Once in the `actionPerformed` method and also within the constructor of your `Math` class.

This code you currently have:

```
Arrays array = new Arrays();
Math math = new Math();
math.cardvalue = 2;
array.clicktracker++;

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array.result);
```

will display the result of the `Arrays` object you created in the `actionPerformed` method - which is null as the result of this object is initialised to null and never set.

This has been mentioned in other answers and comments and will solve it from producing null but this approach will now always yield the same result as you are still always creating a new instance of your `Arrays` class in your `actionPerformed` method.

A better approach would be to separate the logic of the result from the constructor of your `Math` class into another method and create this instance of your `Math` class outside of the `actionPerformed` method. Then within your `actionPerformed` method call your method which will do the logic for your result.

In UI:

```
Math math = new Math();
two.addActionListener(new ActionListener ()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        math.cardvalue = 2;
        math.array.clicktracker++;
        math.calcResult();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,math.array.result);
    }
});
```

In Math:

```
public class Math {
    public int cardvalue;
    public Arrays array;

    public Math()
    {
        array = new Arrays();
    }

    public void calcResult(){
        if (array.clicktracker == 1)
        {   
        //...rest of your logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this fixed the null problem.

Answer (score 2):

In your `Math` constructor, you are changing the result of a different type of `array.result` than the one you are trying to display.

I would consider passing the `Arrays` instance into the `Math` constructor so that you can modify the result from there. Be sure to not reassign the instance though.

---

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        Arrays array = new Arrays();
        Math math = new Math(array);
        math.cardvalue = 2;
        array.clicktracker++;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,array.result);
    }
```

...

```
public Math(Arrays array)
{

    if (array.clicktracker == 1)
    {   
    // And so on ...
```